# CKEditor native browser spell checking *with* tabletools?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 4.4, and hoping to fully enable browser spell checking with it.

The following code enables the spell checker. With this, I get underlining misspelled words, though no right-hand menu of replacement options, as that is overridden:

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
```

When I remove all the following plugins in combination (all seem to be required for this), I the right-hand menu of replacement options is no longer overridden:

```
config.removePlugins = 'scayt,menubutton,liststyle,tabletools,contextmenu';
```

But the better formatting options provided by 'tabletools' are then no longer available.

Has anyone found a solution to have both 'tabletools', and the right hand menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the `Ctrl` key while invoke context menu with right-click. In this case you get browser native context menu.